# Error Inflating class caused by ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, adt, gradle, android-library, dex

Thank you in advance for any help.

I'm using the new build system (gradle) for android.
When building from eclipse the app functions properly.
However, when using the build from gradle, I am having trouble with a referenced library.

When launching the first activity of the library, it works fine. However, once that "loading" activity is done my app crashes when attempting to start the next activity.

In logcat I see:

```
RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo____________ android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class__________
```

...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".Player" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.my.class.name
            android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the com.my.class.name is in the library? I would check that your multi-project setup is correct (if your Java code does not reference the custom view it may not be obvious that the dependency is broken)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Xav. It is now halfway working... In my build.gradle file I actually had to specifically include the library's libs folder in my main project.

Comment: The problem remaining is that I have multiple product flavors in the build.gradle file... I no longer have the problem with one of the flavors, but am getting a resource not found in the other.